# I am having trouble understanding what SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My boss wants to move me into the backend of our company. I have had some experience is developing in MYSQL.

I have started learning Microsoft SQL and all the concepts are pretty straight forward. But I also have to learn SQL Server Integration Services and I am completely stuck.

From what I've read, SSIS are "services" that allow one to extract, transform, and load data. This would be useful, for example, if you are a weather company and need a constant stream of data loading into your database, no?

I know that most of the 'work' in SSIS is done in visual studio, does this mean I have to learn C#?

I am just stuck on the topic. Could anyone recommend any prerequisite topics to look into to better understand SSIS?

Comment: SSIS is typically used for ETL processes that run maybe once daily, not continuous streams of data but I suppose there's no reason why you couldn't have a package scheduled to run at high frequency. C# or VB.NET are useful if you need to write a custom script task but not all packages require this. Just get a book on the topic. It will only take a few days to get the basics.

Comment: "Here's a spreadsheet full of data. Import that into the database" How are you going to do that? Maybe you write little Excel formulas that build out a whole bunch of INSERT statements and run that through SSMS (our MyPHPAdmin tool). Instead of building out the insert statements, SSIS is going to allow you to extract the data from that source, perform any translations on that data, and then load to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand SSIS -- or any other language, tool or technology -- is to learn by doing. I know from 1st hand experience, SSIS can be a little confusing, esp. if you come from a SQL background. That's because SSIS is a graphical way of performing ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) with option to write scripts in both T-SQL as well as C# or .Net in various "tasks" that it exposes.

It also takes some time to get your head around things like "Control Flow" vs "Data Flow" and "Scripting Task" vs "Scripting Component".

Here's a dead-simple explanation of SSIS Basics.

#### [SSIS Basics: Setting Up Your Initial Package](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-setting-up-your-initial-package/)

It's written specifically for someone in your situation (see into note below).

[image]

Then move on to the following MSDN Tutorial

#### [SSIS How to Create an ETL Package.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx)

It walks you through creating a simple ETL Package. Step by Step.

Lastly, remember, The internet is your friend. Simple google searches on what you want to learn more about next will get you up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot in SSIS with the graphical interface and some sql scripts. It is made up of blocks which you join with connectors drag and drop style to determine the order and success/failures paths.

SSIS is normally scheduled as a sql job, but you can also run it manually.

With experience you can build very complex systems .

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/

[tutorial series][1]